# ¿Deberíamos cambiar los literales de "respuestas" en la pantalla de actividad?

Tags: discusión, traducciones

En la pantalla de actividad veo que está "sobrecargada" la palabra "Respuestas" que puede aparecer hasta en tres botones de forma simultánea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Echando un vistazo a la versión inglesa de StackOverflow:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede ver que, tanto en (1) como en (3) se ha traducido "answers" por "respuestas", pero desafortunadamente en (2) se ha tenido que traducir también "responses" por "respuestas".

- El botón (1) lleva a las respuestas escritas por el usuario actual en relación a preguntas de otros usuarios.
- El botón (2) abre una nueva sección con varios tabs que lleva mezcladas, ediciones, comentarios y respuestas que otros usuarios escriben en relación a preguntas/respuestas/comentarios que ha hecho el usuario actual.
- El botón (3) muestra las respuestas que han escrito otros usuarios en relación a preguntas hechas por el usuario actual.

Desde mi punto de vista tenemos tres botones que pueden crear confusión de lo que hacen cada uno.

¿Deberíamos cambiar alguno de estos botones por otros literales? Y, en caso afirmativo, ¿qué literales pondríais a los botones?

Comment: no tengo ni idea que seria ese tab.. interacciones?

Comment: Bien visto! Solo se me ocurre _interacciones entrantes_, pero es demasiado largo. WordReference sugiere también _reacciones_, pero no me convence.

Comment: @fedorqui esto es un trabajo para spanish language????

Comment: @gbianchi démosle ese trabajo :P [¿Cómo se puede diferenciar entre “answers” y “responses” cuando ambas pueden traducirse como “respuestas”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32637/1674)

Comment: @fedorqui Gracias por tomarte la molestia de llevarlo a la comunidad de spanish language. Llevo un rato rompiéndome el coco con alguna palabra que pueda diferenciar una answer y una response. A lo más que he llegado es a "réplicas". A ver si algún experto del lenguaje nos puede arrojar algo de luz.

Comment: La sugerencia que se ha dado es [_reacciones_](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32648/1674)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras [consultarlo en el insigne e inigualable Spanish Language Stack Exchange](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32648/1674), la recomendación es usar ***reacciones*** para lo que en el sitio inglés aparece como 'responses'.

He sugerido el cambio en es.traducir.win: https://es.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=esponse.